# Using nested attributes to update has_one associated record deletes the record and creates a new one instead of updating it's existing attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm working with the models `Phone` and `User`. `Phone` has `country_code`, `area_code` and `phone_number` attributes.

A `Phone` `belongs_to` a `User`, and a `User` `has_one` `default_phone`.

I'm trying to update a `User`'s `default_phone` by using nested attributes:

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :default_phone
  has_one :default_phone, dependent: :destroy, class_name: "Phone"
end
```

Phone model

```
class Phone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :account
end
```

**Problem:** When I update a `User` using nested attributes for `default_phone`, I can see that instead of updating the existing `Phone` record, ActiveRecord deletes the `Phone` record and then creates a new one, leaving all attributes that were not set in the update action as `nil`.

Example:

```
pry(main)> @user.default_phone
=> #<Phone:0x00005597d7827f20
 id: 39,
 account_id: 1,
 user_id: 41,
 country_code: "+55",
 area_code: "55",
 number: "555555555",
 created_at: Thu, 21 Jul 2022 12:18:10 -03 -03:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 21 Jul 2022 12:28:33 -03 -03:00>
```

params:

```
pry(main)> user_params = {:default_phone_attributes=>{
                                :account_id=>1,
                                :area_code=>"11",
                                :number=>"11111111"
                             }
           }
=> {:default_phone_attributes=>{:account_id=>1, :area_code=>"11", number=>"11111111"}}
```

updating `@user` `Phone` with `user_params`:

```
pry(main)> @user.update(user_params)
```

DB transaction:

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Phone Destroy (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "phones" WHERE "phones"."id" = $1  [["id", 39]]
  Account Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER($1) AND "users"."id" != $2 AND "users"."account_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["email", "user_email@mail.com"], ["id", 41], ["account_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Phone Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "phones" ("account_id", "user_id", "area_code", "number", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["account_id", 1], ["user_id", 41], ["area_code", "11"], ["number", "11111111"], ["created_at", "2022-07-21 15:29:02.361105"], ["updated_at", "2022-07-21 15:29:02.361105"]]
(0.6ms)  COMMIT
```

resulting in a new `Phone` record with `country_code` `nil` (as `country_code` was not set in the `user_params`):

```
pry(main)> @user.default_phone
=> #<Phone:0x00005597d74b5a40
 id: 40,
 account_id: 1,
 user_id: 41,
 country_code: nil,
 area_code: "11",
 number: "11111111",
 created_at: Thu, 21 Jul 2022 12:42:40 -03 -03:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 21 Jul 2022 12:42:40 -03 -03:00>
```

Why is the `Phone` being destroyed instead of updated? How can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: You must provide the nested entity's `id` as part of `default_phone_attributes` to get it updated. Or you can set it as `accepts_nested_attributes_for :default_phone, update_only: true` - in this case it will do updates regardless of `id` presence

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov is there a reason to post this as a comment and not an answer?